# como fazer um insert de um input somando o valor ao da coluna do banco de dados? Mysql + php

Tags: php, mysql

Sou iniciante em php e estou fazendo um projeto para tcc do meu curso técnico onde, 
tenho que cadastrar horas de um funcionário.
como faço para que, ao fazer o insert some o valor com o que já está cadastrado no banco?

Comment: Creio que fale de UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

$sql = new Sql();
$sql->select("UPDATE tabela SET 'campos da tabela sem aspas' = bindvalue da tabela mais o valor a ser incrementado");

Não sei se foi bem claro.
Tente nos mandar maiores exemplos.

segue o codigo que estou usando para fazer o insert $sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO HORA( ID_HORA,    NOME_COOPERADO, DT, HORAS_ACUMULADAS) VALUES ( NULL,    :nome, :dt, :horas)"); $sql->bindParam(':nome', $nome, PDO::PARAM_STR); $sql->bindParam(':dt', $dt, PDO::PARAM_STR); $sql->bindParam(':horas', $horas, PDO::PARAM_STR); $sql->execute();

acho melhor você tentar fazer via procedure, porque se não você terá que construir métodos e códigos extensos ao meu ver. Na procedure você coloca pra retornar a hora com incremento de uma variável, pode ser outra coluna na tabela para isso.

Comment: segue o codigo que estou usando para fazer o insert


$sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO HORA(
    ID_HORA,   
    NOME_COOPERADO,
    DT,
    HORAS_ACUMULADAS)
    VALUES (
      NULL,           
      :nome,
      :dt,
      :horas)");
  
  $sql->bindParam(':nome', $nome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $sql->bindParam(':dt', $dt, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $sql->bindParam(':horas', $horas, PDO::PARAM_STR);

  $sql->execute();